# Undefined Reference when trying to Verify Date

Tags: c++

This is my error

/tmp/cce7wiXI.o: In function `main':
ChronoTest.cpp:(.text+0x652): undefined reference to`Chrono::operator>>(std::istream&, Chrono::Date&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This is my header file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace Chrono{
    enum class Month{

    jan=1,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec
    };
    class Date{
        public:

        class Invalid{};

        Date(int y, Month m, int d);
        Date();

        int day() const{return d;}
        Month month()const{return m;}
        int year()const{return y;}


    void add_day(int n);
    void add_month(int n);
    void add_year(int n);

    private:
        int y;
        Month m;
        int d;
    };
    bool is_date(int y, Month m, int d);
    bool leapyear(int y);

    bool operator==(const Date& a, const Date& b);
    bool operator!=(const Date& a, const Date& b);

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d);
    istream& operator>>(istream& is, Date& dd);

    Date& operator++(Date& d);
    Date operator++(Date& dl, int);
}
```

And this is my main file

```
#include "Chrono.h"


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Chrono{

    Date::Date(int yy, Month mm, int dd)
    :y{yy},m{mm},d{dd}
        {
            if(!is_date(yy,mm,dd))throw Invalid();
        }

        const Date& default_date()
        {
            static Date dd{2001,Month::jan,1};
            return dd;
            }
            Date::Date()
            :y{default_date().year()},
            m{default_date().month()},
            d{default_date().day()}{}
void Date::add_day(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
    ++d;
    if(!is_date(y, m, d)){
        d = 1;
        if(m == Month::dec){
            m = Month::jan;
            ++y;
        }else
            m = Month(static_cast<int>(m)+1);
    }
    }
}
void Date::add_month(int n){

}
void Date::add_year(int n){
    if (m==Month::feb&& d==29&&!leapyear(y+n)){
        m = Month::mar;
        d=1;
    }
    y+=n;
}

bool is_date(int y, Month m, int d)
{
    if(d<=0)return false;
    if(m<Month::jan || Month::dec<m)return false;

    int days_in_month = 31;

    switch(m){
        case Month::feb:
            days_in_month = (leapyear(y))?29:28;
            break;
        case Month::apr:case Month::jun:case Month::sep:case Month::nov:
             days_in_month = 30;
            break;
    }
    if(days_in_month<d)return false;
    return true;
}
bool leapyear(int y)
{
    return false;
}
bool operator==(const Date& a, const Date& b)
{
    return a.year()==b.year()
    &&a.month()==b.month()
    &&a.day()==b.day();
}
bool operator!=(const Date& a, const Date& b)
{
    return !(a==b);
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d)
{
    return os<<'('<<d.year()
             <<','<<static_cast<int>(d.month())
             <<','<<d.day()<<')';
}
istream& operator<<(istream& is, Date& dd)
{
    int y, m, d;
    char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;
    is>>ch1>>y>>ch2>>m>>ch3>>d>>ch4;
    if(!is)return is;
    if(ch1!='('||ch2!=','||ch3!=','||ch4!=')'){
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    dd = Date(y, Month(m), d);
    return is;
}
Date operator++(Date& d1, int)
{
    Date d2 = d1;
    d1.add_day(1);
    return d2;
}
enum class Day{
    sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday
};

Day day_of_week(const Date& d)
{

}
Date next_Sunday(const Date& d)
{
    return d;
}
Date next_weekday(const Date& d)
{
    return d;
}
}
int main()
try
{

    using namespace Chrono;
    cout << "enter some dates: ";
    Date d;
    cin>> d;
    cout<< d << "is a valid date!";

    // For some Windows(tm) setups
}
catch (Chrono::Date::Invalid&) {
    cerr << "error: Invalid date\n"; 
    // For some Windows(tm) setup
    return 1;
}
catch (runtime_error& e) {  // this code is to produce error messages
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
    // For some Windows(tm) setups
}
```

I'm trying to input a date to validate if it is a real day or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature in your header is:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Date& dd);
```

This is incorrect in your implementation file:

```
istream& operator<<(istream& is, Date& dd)
//               ^^ Should be >>
```